# Spring Data repository case sensitive query

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I created a simple query in a repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
[...]
   @Query("SELECT user FROM User user "
        + "where user.userName= :userName "
        + "and user.password= :password "
        + "and  user.organization.name= :organizationName")
   User findByNamePasswordOrganization(@Param("userName") String userName,
        @Param("password") String password,
        @Param("organizationName") String organizationName);
[...]
```

but the result is case insensitive, so if userName="USER" or username="user" is the same for this query.

I use Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE, Spring Data 1.8.0.RELEASE, Hibernate 4.0.1.Final and MySql 5.6

EDIT:

I've resolved with native query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USER user, ORGANIZATION organization "
        + "where user.USER_NAME= ?1 "
        + "and BINARY user.PASSWORD= ?2 "
        + "and organization.name= ?3 "
        + "and user.ORGANIZATION_ID=organization.ORGANIZATION_ID", nativeQuery = true)
User findByNamePasswordOrganizationSql(String userName, String password, String organizationName);
```

Comment: I believe MySQL is case insensitive by default. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 2):

MySQL is case insensitive unless you do a binary comparison http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-op.html

By the way using Spring data you dont need the @Query just use the interface method definition

```
   User findByUserNameAndPasswordAndOrganizationName(@Param("userName") String userName,
    @Param("password") String password,
    @Param("organizationName") String organizationName)
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/
Section 4.3.2. Query creation